# JSP form parameters disappear when I POST my form to another page

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, forms, post

If I leave the `action` attribute out of my form so it posts back to the same JSP I have no trouble reading the request parameters.  However when I add an `action` attribute to handle the form with a separate JSP, the request parameters are `null`.  Here's a short example (`FormTest.jsp`) that illustrates how I'm reading the request.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>FormTest.jsp</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H3>Using a Single Form</H3>
        <%
            String command = request.getParameter("submit");
        %>
            You clicked <%= command %>

        <FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST">
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="First">
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Second">
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Third">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The above page works as expected.  Initially the page prints `You clicked null` along with the form.  Clicking any of the three buttons changes the message to `You clicked First`, etc.

Now I change just one line in the page above to add the `action` attribute:

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="FormHandler.jsp">
```

I added a separate JSP to my project to read the request parameter as follows:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>FormHandler.jsp</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H3>Form Handler</H3>
        <%
            String command = request.getParameter("submit");
        %>
            You clicked <%= command %>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I expected the new `FormHandler.jsp` to just print out which button was pressed on the other page, but it seems the request parameter is always `null`.

What could be interfering with the request parameters being sent to a separate JSP?

#### Update:

This project has a JSF configuration file as well.  I changed the `action` attribute to `ACTION="FormHandler.faces"` and the code above works but I don't quite understand why yet.  Here's the method that's redirecting requests that end in `.jsp`.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();

    if (uri.endsWith(".jsp")) {
        int length = uri.length();
        String newAddress = uri.substring(0, length - 3) + ".faces";
        response.sendRedirect(newAddress);
    }
    else { //Address ended in "/"
        response.sendRedirect("login.faces");
    }
}
```

Now I guess I need to know 1) how to figure out if this is the source of the problem, and 2) is there a way to preserve the request parameters when the response is redirected?

There's also an entry in the `web.xml` configuration file for this project that sets a filter mapping.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>faces-redirect-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I suppose (but it's probably clear by now that I'm new to JSF, so someone correct me if I'm wrong) that using the `.faces` extension in my `action` attribute bypasses this filter.

Comment: What is your environment?  I just pasted your examples into Tomcat 6.0.24 and it worked fine.

Comment: @Affe: I'm running this in WebLogic 9.2.  This project also has a JSF configuration file that I'm looking at right now to see if I can find the source of the problem.

Comment: I can agree with Affe that it works with Tomcat. Do you see the request in the net view of firebug?

Comment: @kukudas: Thanks.  Unfortunately I'm at work using IE6, so no firebug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`POST` parameters are lost because `sendRedirect()` sends a `302 Moved Temporarily` redirect, which instructs the browser to load the specified page with `GET` request.

To retain parameters you need to use `307 Temporary Redirect` instead - it instructs the browser to repeat a `POST` request to the specifed URI:

```
response.setHeader("Location", newAddress); 
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
```